# How can i display multiple result in a series of textboxs?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem populating multiple data to multiple textboxes. I've attached a link to the project so that you guys can get the picture.

[image]

Thank you so much in advance! I'm no wiz programmer. :)

EDIT: heres the code

```
` Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost; user id=root; password=dctvmainadmin; database=tmsdctv")
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM recordedattendance WHERE empno = '00111' and dateattended = '2014-02-03 Mon'"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim result As New System.Data.DataTable

    con.Open()
    Dim Cmd_Read_Name As New MySqlCommand(query)
    Cmd_Read_Name.Connection = con
    result.Load(Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader)

    With Me
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In result.Rows
            .lblEmpno.Text = dtrow(0)
            .lblDate1.Text = dtrow(1)
            .txtTimeIn1.Text = dtrow(2)
            .txtTimeOut1.Text = dtrow(3)
        Next
        con.Close()
    End With`
```

Comment: there fixed no of record...

Comment: What do you mean bro?

Comment: Show your code then we can help you..

Comment: My code only displays one row for each `row` of textbox what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I already edit my post :)

Comment: I already did that but it only displays the last row of the database

Comment: `.lblDate2.Text = dtrow(4)
.txtTimeIn2.Text = dtrow(5)
.txtTimeOut2.Text = dtrow(6)` and if i do it like this it show "cannot find column 4"

Comment: no one out there can help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This:

Specifing textbox lable name like:

**lblEmpno1,lblEmpno2,lblEmpno3.., lblDate1,lblDate2,lblDate3....,
     txtTimeIn1,txtTimeIn2,txtTimeIn3..., txtTimeOut1,txtTimeOut2,txtTimeOut3....**

```
 Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost; 
 user id=root; password=dctvmainadmin; database=tmsdctv")
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM recordedattendance WHERE empno
    = '00111' and dateattended = '2014-02-03 Mon'"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim result As New System.Data.DataTable

    con.Open()
    Dim Cmd_Read_Name As New MySqlCommand(query)
    Cmd_Read_Name.Connection = con
    result.Load(Cmd_Read_Name.ExecuteReader)

       For xi as integer=0 to result.Rows.Count-1
            Controls("lblEmpno" & xi+1  &).Text  .Text = result.Rows(xi).Item(0)
            Controls("lblDate" & xi+1  &).Text = result.Rows(xi).Item(1)
            Controls("txtTimeIn" & xi+1  &).Text = result.Rows(xi).Item(2)
            Controls("txtTimeOut" & xi+1  &).Text = result.Rows(xi).Item(3)
        Next
        con.Close()
```

Comment: yes i'm checking it right now.. thank you so much. Buts its not working "blue lines"

Comment: 'Property access must assign to the property or use its value' errror

Comment: the lbl's and txt's inside the for

Comment: sorry for the late reply i will check it out

Comment: it says 'expression expected' in this part "&)."

Comment: did you type the code like this `Controls("Textbox" & i + 1&).Text = "elcabronel"` @elcabronel

Comment: yes i did remove it and got no error, however when i query for the data in mysql "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @elcabronel I did not change your query

Comment: DUDE!!!! You save my life! Thank you thank you thank you! How can i thank you personally? thank you so much! Its working now!

Comment: SATSON bro, can you explain to me what did you do in that code?

Comment: `result.Rows.Count-1` i change this to this `result.Columns.Count - 1`

Comment: @elcabronel Find the Controls in that form using control name and assign the value in the particular control. That add in that code in side the for loop

Comment: It's working bro but it only displays the first 4 rows of the list view then repeat all 4 to the rest of the textbox, check out the ss http://s26.postimg.org/plwizw9jt/image.png

Comment: @elcabronel Post your for loop coding

Comment: http://s26.postimg.org/m4ugwxahl/image.png heres the code it solely based on your solution

Comment: Change result.column.count-1 to result.Rows.Count-1 @elcabronel

Comment: If i change result.column.count-1 to result.Rows.Count-1 it display's an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: result is data table or not @elcabronel

Comment: sorry if i'm making this long but i just wanted to make my application work. :(

Comment: Then 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' this error msg is not possible put the break point near for loop and check the datatable have value or not @elcabronel

Comment: DUDE! Im here to say thank you so much! :) you saved my life again with this chunk of code! I hope you continue to help noobs like me. Thank you so much!